# How to place a chart across multiple columns of a table in Report Builder/SSRS

Tags: ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-grouping

I'm trying to place a chart across multiple columns of a table in Report Builder (because I'm trying to emulate a colleague's chart. I tried creating a rectangle, but I cannot get the rectangle to span more than one column. Thanks!

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: What I'm trying to achieve:]

Here's what I have now:

[image: What I have now:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is just to merge the cells in the top row.

The reason why I don't want to have one column is that I need the interior table width to be smaller than the chart width.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a parent tablix with two rows and one column. Put the chart in the first row and the table in the second. That way you can manage them completely independently but still have them tied together in the layout / formatting.